# Sharepoint PnP List: How to "Group by" columns using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I want to group a Sharepoint list by a column using powershell, so when users access this list, it's already grouped.
I know the List settings already has this [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-grouping-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-18548b63-a869-4fcf-89b1-ba3d04784df7), but I want to be able to control this via a powershell script that resets the list to data read from a local server.
Below images provide additional clarity of my question.

[Columns not grouped together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC1u9.png)

[Columns grouped together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id8re.png)

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked into the `-Aggregations` param on `Set-PnPView`?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a reference of below powershell script:

```
#Set Variables
$SiteURL = "https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/s01"
$ListName = "your list name"

$Username='admin@abc.onmicrosoft.com'
$Password = 'xxxx'

#region Credentials
[SecureString]$SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force 
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$PSCredentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username, $SecurePass) 
#endregion Credentials
 
#Connect to PNP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $PSCredentials

#Get the Client Context
$Context = Get-PnPContext
  
#Get the List View
$View = Get-PnPView -Identity "All Items" -List $ListName
  
$Context.Load($View)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
  
$View.ViewQuery

$ViewQuery = '<GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="30"><FieldRef Name="num" /></GroupBy>' + $View.ViewQuery
  
#Update the view Query
$View.ViewQuery = $ViewQuery
$View.Update()
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

More references:

- https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/04/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-update-list-view.html
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpview?view=sharepoint-ps

BR